# Converting existing 3-way switches to smart switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I have an existing 3-way switch setup that I'm trying to convert to "smart" switches and I'm feeling "not smart" after mapping out where I think the wires are going.  Unfortunately I don't have a good wiring diagram to share with you besides this back of the napkin drawing where yellow = white wire.

[image: back of the napkin drawing]

Box A: This is a double gang box. There are 2 switches and 4 cables in this box.  The first switch is a leg of the 3-way switch to entryway chandelier (20 feet overhead, I have no access to the fixture box so I don't know how it's wired).
The other switch (referred to as switch 3) is to an outside light.  I only mention it for completeness and the fact that it's using the same 14/2 line as the 3-way switches of interest.

```
Box A two gang
    cable 1 - 14/3 romex
        black - switch 1 traveler (switched hot)
        red - switch 1 traveler (always hot)
        white - nutted to cable 2 red
    
    cable 2 - 14/3 romex
        black - wired to switch 1 oddball/common terminal (always hot)
        red - nutted to cable 1 white
        white - neutral

    cable 3 - 14/2 romex
        black - line (always hot)
        white - neutral
    
    cable 4 - 14/2 romex
        black - switch 3 load (to outside light)
        white - neutral (from outside light)

all neutrals in box nutted together (cable 2, cable 3, cable 4)
cable 3 black (line) nutted to: (cable 2 black, switch 1 oddball, switch 3 line)
```

Box B: This is a single gang box. There is only 1 cable in this box.  This is the other leg of the 3-way switch to entryway chandelier.  Presumably this cable is the other end of cable 1 in Box A, since when the circuit is off that wire behaves the same in each box (red is hot, black and white are off).

```
Box B single gang
    cable 1 - 14/3 romex (presumably other end of Box A wire 1)
        black - switch 2 (switched hot)
        red - switch 2 (always hot)
        white - switch 2 oddball/common terminal (switched hot)
```

Okay... so now my question is ultimately twofold: What is most probable wiring diagram for the chandelier fixture box, and can I rewire for a smart switch & add on without having to change the wiring at the fixture?

I am presuming that Box A cable 2 is going up to the fixture. If that's true, I'm at a loss as to why 14/3 is used for this purpose.

Edited:
Here are some photos of the switch boxes.
[image: Switch Box B]
[image: Switch Box A]

Comment: _"I don't have a good wiring diagram to share with you"_ -- please fix that. Anyone else who would like to help is going to have to translate all of the words above into a diagram anyway, either in their head, or on actual paper. You should respect the community enough to do that work _once_ yourself, instead of making each reader repeat the effort.

Comment: a) What you are referring to as Wire 1, 2, 3, 4 are normally referred to as **cables**. Please rewrite as it will be less confusing since there are actual individual colored **wires**. b) With the exception of cable 2 (incoming power), how are you determining "switched hot" and "always hot"? c) **PICTURES** Please upload pictures showing all these cables/wires and switches - that will help a lot; d) On 3-way switches, normally the 2 travelers will have one color screw and the 1 other wire (hot or switched hot) has a different color (typical colors are black, silver, brass) - please list those

Comment: screw colors matched to wire colors and a lot of this will quickly make more sense.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact sorry about the cable/wires thing.  I'll see if I can clean it up.  I will try to get some pictures, but it's a rat's nest in there.  Yes the common/oddball terminal is depicted in my drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the diagram (with yellow => white), it looks pretty straightforward, *but actual pictures instead of drawings would confirm the details*:

Box A:

- Cable 1 = 3-way. Red & Black = travelers. White = switched hot.
- Cable 2 = Light fixture. Red = switched hot. Black = always hot *for use in other stuff past the light fixture*. White = neutral.
- Cable 3 = Incoming power. Black = hot. White = neutral.
- Cable 4 = Outside light. Black = switched hot. White = neutral.

Box B:

- Red & Black = travelers. White = switched hot.

For your smart switch, install it in Box A. You will probably need a neutral - just add it to the bunch of existing neutrals.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Your explanation about the 14/3 to the fixture for future use makes sense.  If my add-on switch requires just a neutral and traveler, do I just cap off the other traveler in each box and repurpose white as neutral?

Comment: Hard to say what the 2nd switch (Box B) will need - depends on the design of the smart switch. But yes, if the end result is that it takes a neutral then **neutral must be white** and if the end result is that it does **not** take a neutral but that it also **only needs 2 wires** then you should rearrange the wires so that white is capped both ends and black & red used instead.